# onclick add value to mysql ( wordpress ) frontend

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to make a button that when clicked, adds a value to user meta in Wordpress. This is what I have so far:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="test" id="test" value="RUN" /><br/>
</form>
```

My test function:

```
function test()
{
    $user_id = 11;
    $kscoins = '1000';
    update_user_meta($user_id, '_ywpar_user_total_points', $kscoins);
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Also, how can I add the value to the current value?

**Example:** If value is `500` can I add `500` more to equal `1000`?

Comment: Have you added this function to an action/hook? If not, that's a good place to start. Second, you would probably want to get the meta first for the existing value, then sum the new and existing, then update.

Comment: Im not sure how i could do that.

Right now this code is just a Proof of concept for something i want to build in the future.

I need a quick way to add values to this table.
But i can seem to make it add this value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you will want to add a function to a hook, like `init` or `wp_loaded`, something like this (I have not tested this, but you can investigate further if this doesn't work for some reason):

```
function addUserPoints()
{
    # Don't do anything if nothing submitted
    if(empty($_POST['test']))
        return false;
    # Get the current user's id
    $id = get_current_user_id();
    # If no one logged in, stop
    if(empty($id))
        return false;
    # Get the points for the current user
    $getPoints = get_user_meta($id, '_ywpar_user_total_points', true);
    # If no points, add the 500
    if(empty($getPoints))
        add_user_meta($id, '_ywpar_user_total_points', 500);
    # If there are points already, sum them and update
    else
        update_user_meta($id, '_ywpar_user_total_points', ($getPoints + 500));
}
# Add your function to an hook
add_action('wp_loaded', 'addUserPoints');
```

Comment: this look great, I can understand this. Ill give it a go and see what i can do with this.